# How can I use calculated fields in a WHERE clause with MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have query like this:

```
SELECT client_id,name, last_name, email,  date_arrival,
  DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) as date6before  FROM clients WHERE agent_id = 4 
    and  date_arrival > date6before
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the value in where again:

```
SELECT client_id,name, last_name, email,  date_arrival,
  DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) as date6before  FROM clients WHERE agent_id = 4 
    and  date_arrival > DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

or using `having` clause

```
SELECT client_id,name, last_name, email,  date_arrival,
  DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) as date6before  FROM clients WHERE agent_id = 4 
    having  date_arrival > date6before
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT temp.* FROM (SELECT client_id,name, last_name, email,  date_arrival, DATE_SUB(now(),INTERVAL 6 DAY) as date6before  FROM clients WHERE agent_id = 4 ) as temp WHERE temp.date_arrival > date6before
```